# data aggregation and invalid data type message?

Tags: r

I have been stuck on how to aggregate some date for a while.

```
 DF2 <- aggregate(.~fund, cbind(DF["fund"], test[assets_cols]), sum)
```

I am receiving the following error message,

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = cbind() ~ fund, data = cbind(test["fund"],  : 
>     invalid type (NULL) for variable 'cbind()'

```
 DF

 name   fund      2018_11_return 2018_12_return 2018_11_assets 2018_12_assets
 ab1 xcdfjxxv123         3.154       3.18         34234234234     546454543
 ds1 xcdfjxxv123         3.123       4.28         31231234234     454684543
 ad8 sdfffesg124         6.523       6.78         61121234234     234684543 
 t68 sdfffesg124          7.723       8.88         12232234234     5234684543
```

Any help is appreciated. The actual data set contains many more rows and the groups are not always the same size. I would like the output as a new data frame.

Sorry for such a basic question

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: @sotos I would like to aggregate the assets by fund for each year

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using data.table that sums all _assets columns by year and fund:

**set up**

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table("name" = c("ab1", "ds1", "ad8", "t68"),
                "fund" = c("fund1","fund1","fund2","fund2"),
                "2018_11_assets" = 1:4,
                "2018_12_assets" = 101:104,
                "2019_11_assets" = 10:13,
                "2019_12_assets" = 110:113)

   name  fund 2018_11_assets 2018_12_assets 2019_11_assets 2019_12_assets
1:  ab1 fund1              1            101             10            110
2:  ds1 fund1              2            102             11            111
3:  ad8 fund2              3            103             12            112
4:  t68 fund2              4            104             13            113
```

**solution**

```
dt = melt(data = dt, id.vars = c("name", "fund")) # convert to long data
dt[, year := as.numeric(substr(variable, 0, 4))] #extract the year
dt[, .(assets = sum(value)), by = .(fund, year)] # aggregate

    fund year assets
1: fund1 2018    206
2: fund2 2018    214
3: fund1 2019    242
4: fund2 2019    250
```